# How do I search online URL's and directories with python

Tags: python, search, directory

I'm familiar but not exactly great with python.

I'm wondering if there is a way/module in python that would allow me to search a local folder (and/or website directory) for files that have a certain pattern in their name (ex. all files that begin with "w1020").

If you have a code, could you please explain the various modules and their exact functions... or leave links that would explain.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use [regular expressions](http://www.diveinto.org/python3/regular-expressions.html) to find strings that match a certain pattern, but for the example application you give this might be a little bit too heavy.

For a local folder you can use the built-in string functions:

```
for file_path in os.listdir(r"C:\temp"):
    if file_path.startswith("w1020"):
        print(file_path)
```

For a website, you might do well to search for a pre-made module. However, [this tutorial](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/scraping-websites-with-beautifulsoup/) gives a few examples that you can combine with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

The code for a local directory would be pretty simple:

```
import os

PATH = '/tmp'

for f in os.listdir(PATH):
    if os.path.isfile(f) and f.startswith('w1020'):
        print f
```

Output example:

```
w1020bob.doc
w1020abc.test
```

The [os](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) module contains lots of useful functions for manipulating files and directories. `os.listdir` gives a list of all files in a directory. I think the rest of the code is pretty self-explanatory.

A website directory is a whole other ballgame. It's up to the webserver whether they give you a list of files at all, and the files will be shown in html however the webserver wants. So you'll have to parse the html to get that. [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is pretty good at that.

It's also possible that you're talking about [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) in which case it would probably be easiest just to mount it as a local directory and use the above code.

Comment: thank you so much for the help! could u please explain wut '/tmp' is though.

Comment: ```/tmp``` is just a unix directory. If you are on windows you might use something like ```r'C:\Temp\'```. The ```r``` makes it a raw string so you don't have to escape all the ```\```'s.